# How do i create a pivot table in excel which contains an "average price" column

Tags: excel

Not really sure if this is a right question to ask on stackoverflow so let me know if there's a better place, but it is such a basic question without a clear answer (that I can find).

Lets say I have a table of transactions with 3 columns:

1. ItemName
2. PurchasePrice
3. PurchaseQuantity

I want to create a pivot table that has the avg price per item name. In SQL, it would simply be:

`select ItemName, SUM(PurchasePrice)/SUM(PurchaseQuantity) from table group by ItemName`

How do I do the same in excel.

Comment: You can do that without a pivot table, just using sql on sheet data an copy the result in any place in your book.

Answer (score 0):

In pivot table, add a calculated field haning the formula: =SUM(PurchasePrice) / SUM(PurchaseQuantity) and name it AVG.

[image]

**and using VBA SQL (without a pivot table):** with a small variation creating a sum column for the quantities.

```vb
    Option Explicit

    Sub sqlAverage(Optional destination As Range = Nothing)
       Dim connection As Object, recSet As Object, sql As String
       
       sql = "SELECT [ItemName], SUM([PurchaseQuantity]) AS CNT, ROUND(SUM([PurchasePrice])/SUM([PurchaseQuantity]),4) AS AVER FROM [SHEET07$V1:X8] GROUP BY [ItemName] ORDER BY [ItemName]"
       Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
       With connection
          .CursorLocation = 3
          .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
          .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
          .Open
          Set recSet = .Execute(sql)
       End With
       If Not destination Is Nothing Then
          Call destination.CopyFromRecordset(recSet)
       End If
       recSet.Close
       connection.Close
       Set recSet = Nothing
       Set connection = Nothing
    End Sub
    
    Sub tester()
       Call sqlAverage(Me.Range("V12"))
    End Sub
```